# Tabular Joomla Menu

Tags: php, joomla

I am trying to convert the default menu created in Joomla, with UL-LI, to a tabular menu, i.e. table-tr-td-a, any help on how to extend the default behavior.

Sorry if this sounds noob, but I am one on for Joomla!

Comment: why on earth would you want to use a table structure in a menu? If you need another menu, simply search on the [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/) site

Comment: @Lodder I understand mate, the TABULAR layout for navigation, is primitive and sounds lame, but I am stuck here with converting a static site into CMS without any possibilities of re-design

Answer (score 0):

To do this you'd need to edit the default.php file in the ftp by going to modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default.php in the ftp. You'll see they echo the ul,li etc elements. You'd just need to replace these with the table codes.

Alternatively you can download something from the [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/) with a table structure. However most people find ul/li elements much better so you might struggle.

On a side note tables are much slower than ul,li etc elements for menus so I really wouldn't advice it. But whatever floats your boat!!

Comment: thanks mate for your inputs here, after few googling I got aware about the mod_menu, but I don't consider it as a good practice to edit the core files, there could be something by which i could extend the files and provide new layout for menu, or Joomla could have something like wp_nav_menu as available in Wordpress

Comment: @Sankalp Shekhar You can install a new module if you want! There's plenty out there. I'm afraid I don't have much clue about Wordpress. If you don't want to write core files then You can put in a display override in the template

Comment: thanks for the heads up, I used the TEMPLATE OVERRIDE to get over this